# Magento 1.9.3 invoice tax template

Tags: invoice, tax

I'm having problems finding the right template to modify the tax in invoice file (look at attached image).

[image]

I want to make tax (in my case 'Käibemaks 20%') as small as the subtotal and total.
I managed to edit subtotal and total successfully in totals.phtml file, but cant seem to find the correct file or place for tax.

Thanks in advance for any help!

FORGOT TO MENTION: I'm using Fooman PDF customizer and email attachments modules